# Problem with chat.postMessage - channel_not_foud

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to use the postMessage to send a form but I recive a error channel_not_found when I test, but when my friend test its works.

```
slackWeb.im.open({token: secrets.token, user: data.user}).then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                let msg = msgs.k
                msg.user = data.user
                msg.channel = res.channel.id
                console.log(res.channel.id)
                slackWeb.chat.postMessage(msg)
            })
```

[Image of the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukprs.png)

Comment: is that a private channel? possibly is user of your token is not a member of that channel. try testing with a public channel

Answer (score 0):

Does your key have `channel:read` permissions?